# Cryptic with missing capitals

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-crosswords

Solve the clues and fill the grid. Each clue is missing a different **European capital city**.

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>
> 1. Funny beret men strike $??$ to convene (4)
>   3. Containers found in a $??$ plaza (4)
>   5. Ten $??$ site's leaders return after first state, shortly (4)
>   6. Ethnic group is $??$, locally (4)
>   7. Dmitry's $??$ chamber first for union's capital (4)
>   8. Hideout between left and right, return $??$'s finals (4)
>   9. Certain banks of $??$ river encircle central dome (4)
>   10. $??$'s extremities leave metals for baseballers (4)
>   11. Stalk Dorothy's aunt following the heart of $??$ (4)
>   13. Moody people's fringe expressions outside $??$'s borders (4)
>   14. Half-heartedly, $??$ first lady makes money (4)
>   15. In the middle of chaotic $??$, doctor gets cut (4)
>   16. Asteroid buried in the back country of $??$ (4)
>   17. Constituents of $??$'s republic passed with flying colours (4)
>   18. Arrest $??$'s top three; capital punishment follows (4)
>   19. Listen, Sparta $??$ to be overflowing (4)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Created the second-to-last little $??$ statue with no rim (4)
>   2. Wanting an I, $??$ head master leads to transport (4)
>   3. Friends immediately south of $??$, third one climbing up (4)
>   4. $??$ couple hides in tube below street under pressure (8)
>   5. Head of state visits Namib and Gobi for $??$ Fingers, among others (8)
>   11. $??$'s central assistants preparing leaders for strike (4)
>   12. $??$'s central trio on top-tier market, briefly (4)
>   13. Henry IV leaves the last bits of $??$ cheese (4)

Note:

> For the purposes of this puzzle I did not include **Baku**, **Nicosia**, **Tbilisi** or **Yerevan** (all of which could be European depending on which definition one uses).

Comment: Ah, you did a neat thing again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Funny beret men strike ?? to convene (4)

> Insert BERN; solution is MEET: (BERETMEN-BERN)*

3. Containers found in a ?? plaza (4)

> Insert BERLIN; solution is POTS, found in POTSdamer Platz

5. Ten ?? site's leaders return after first state, shortly (4)

> Insert ATHENS; solution is DECA: AC(ropolis) backwards after DE(laware). I'm not terribly confident about this one.

6. Ethnic group is ??, locally (4)

> Insert ROMA; solution is ROMA (Italian name for Rome)

7. Dmitry's ?? chamber first for union's capital (4)

> Insert MOSCOW; solution is DIMA: DUMA with I in place of U

8. Hideout between left and right, return ??'s finals (4)

> Insert SOFIA; solution is LAIR: IA between L and R

9. Certain banks of ?? river encircle central dome (4)

> Insert PARIS; solution is SOME: banks of S(ein)E encircle (d)OM(e)

10. ??'s extremities leave metals for baseballers (4)

> Insert LJUBLJANA; solution is METS (METALS minus AL)

11. Stalk Dorothy's aunt following the heart of ?? (4)

> Insert PRISTINA; solution is STEM: EM after ST

13. Moody people's fringe expressions outside ??'s borders (4)

> Insert MONACO; solution is EMOS (ES outside MO)

14. Half-heartedly, ?? first lady makes money (4)

> Insert RIGA; solution is RIAL (RI(g)A + L)

15. In the middle of chaotic ??, doctor gets cut (4)

> Insert MADRID; solution is AMID: (MADRID-DR)*

16. Asteroid buried in the back country of ?? (4)

> Insert BUCHAREST; solution is AMOR, found backwards in ROMANIA

17. Constituents of ??'s republic passed with flying colours (4)

> Insert SKOPJE; solution is ACED, found inside (North) MACEDONIA

18. Arrest ??'s top three; capital punishment follows (4)

> Insert STOCKHOLM; solution is STOP: STO(ckholm) + P(unishment)

19. Listen, Sparta ?? to be overflowing (4)

> Insert PRAGUE; solution is TEEM (apparently "Sparta Prague" is a sporting team; thanks to Fillet for finding this)

Down

1. Created the second-to-last little ?? statue with no rim (4)

> Insert COPENHAGEN; solution is MADE: (Little) MERMAID with its second letter moved to the end (MRMAIDE) and letters of RIM removed

2. Wanting an I, ?? head master leads to transport (4)

> Insert TIRANA; solution is TRAM: T(i)R(an)A + M(aster)

3. Friends immediately south of ??, third one climbing up (4)

> Insert VADUZ; solution is PALS: ALPS with third letter P climing up to top

4. ?? couple hides in tube below street under pressure (8)

> Insert BRUSSELS; answer is STRESSED: SS in REED below ST

5. Head of state visits Namib and Gobi for ?? Fingers, among others (8)

> Insert VIENNA solution is DESSERTS: S inside DESERTS

11. ??'s central assistants preparing leaders for strike (4)

> Insert OSLO solution is SLAP: (o)SL(o) + A(ssistants) P(reparing)

12. ??'s central trio on top-tier market, briefly (4)

> Insert SAN MARINO; solution is MART: MAR on top of TIER

13. Henry IV leaves the last bits of ?? cheese (4)

> Insert AMSTERDAM; solution is EDAM: ERDAM minus IVth letter of HENRY

Grid:

> ```
>       M E E T     P O T S
> D E C A     R O M A     T
> E     D I M A     L A I R
> S O M E     M E T S     E
> S                       S
> E     S T E M     E M O S
> R I A L     A M I D     E
> T     A M O R     A C E D
> S T O P     T E E M
> ```

Notice that

> the *solutions*, not merely the *spaces*, are rotationally symmetrical.

Credit where due:

> I didn't figure out 19a myself and probably never would have; Fillet found it; please consider upvoting their answer if you like this one.

Comment: Hm, second should of course be "first" in 7a... Fixing that now.

Comment: +1, very impressive, I think I have the correct explanations for 19a and 1d in my answer.

Comment: I just figured out 1d (though I think the clue is broken); haven't looked at your answer but will do so now.

Comment: Looks like we agree on 1d. Your answer to 19a sounds very plausible and I'll edit into my answer with appropriate credit.

Comment: No indirect anagram in 1d, it's another type of wordplay :) I think I get the confusion, though... The indicator would probably make more sense after the thing it modifies, not before.

Comment: D'oh, I see. Will edit. [EDITED to add:] Done.

Answer (score 15):

Given that

> The ?? is to be replaced by a european capital city for each clue

Here are a few:

1a Funny beret men strike ?? to convene (4).

> Meet (City is Bern, anagram of beretmen - Bern)

8a Hideout between left and right, return ??'s finals (4)

> Lair (City is Sofia, last two letters backwards between l and r). Nicosia would also have fit if the definition of Europe had included it.

11. Stalk Dorothy's aunt following the heart of ?? (4)

> Stem (Aunt **Em** from Wizard of Oz following Pri**st**ina)

15a. In the middle of chaotic ??, doctor gets cut (4)

> Amid (City is Madrid, anagram without dr)

17a. Constituents of ??'s republic passed with flying colours (4)

> Aced (City: Skopje, capital of [North?] M**aced**onia)

18a. Arrest ??'s top three; capital punishment follows (4)

> Stop (City is Stockholm, giving Sto, then p from punishment)

19a. Listen, Sparta ?? to be overflowing (4)

> Teem (City is Prague, Sparta Prague is a team)

1d Created the second-to-last little ?? statue with no rim (4)

> Made (City is Copenhagen, statue there is Mermaid (mermaid - rim = mead, move the e from second to last position = made)

4d. ?? couple hides in tube below street under pressure (8)

> Stressed? St for street, and a reed? Not sure of the city though?

12d. ??'s central trio on top-tier market, briefly (4)

> Mart (City is San **mar**ino + top **t**ier)

Comment: Nice start! I've added a note regarding 8a.

Comment: 4d: rot13(Jbhyqa'g gur ghor ersre gb Ybaqba?)

Answer (score 3):

13down:

> Henry IV = fourth letter of HENRY = R, city = Amsterdam (Netherlands), last bits of AMSTERDAM = ERDAM, ERDAM - R = EDAM (a cheese from Holland!).

---