# Cryptic Crossword with Missing LUGs

Tags: wordplay, geography, crosswords, cryptic-crosswords

Inspired by jafe's [Cryptic with missing capitals](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80130/cryptic-with-missing-capitals) and Tzu Li's [Tokyo Metro puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80144/tokyo-metro-puzzle):

Solve the clues and fill the grid. Each clue is missing a different London Underground Station

As jafe has noted in [Traversing Africa: A Cryptic Journey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80282/traversing-africa-a-cryptic-journey):

> By request of the Sanity Preservation Institute, some long names have been shortened. For example, if the full place name is "Xyz Royal National Park", the answer will be just "Xyz" (often with "royal national park" or similar as the definition).

Now, here we go:
[image: The Clues]
** Edited clue for 12D to enhance clarity

Text transcription of clues:

**Across:**
1. Big at first, ?? without direction is flash of lightning (4)
2. Limits of ?? shows time of year (5)
3. Initially courteous, ?? is king out of lair (7)
4. First half of ?? watched Polish city (6)
5. First slice of ?? blended becomes little boy (3)
6. Beheaded ?? misheard as nation (7)
7. Head-on horse on ?? With alien makes protective accessory (6)
8. ?? without misheard alarm matters dimensions (4)
9. A situation around the head of ?? being Anglican (12)
10. Bizzare ??, with two more piece of instrument (8)
11. Talk rudely below the ?? (5)

**Down:**
1. Dark part of messy ?? is unprecedented event (5 4)
12. Nameless ?? in the past: evil (6)
13. Shortened church ahead of ?? without meat is meat (7)
14. Poor ?? with leg crossed wounds (5)
15. Extreme ?? in shallow hot open pool is diagonal wanderer (6)
16. Scrambled ?? following the Honourable with initialized Delhi University is American country (8)
17. Counting section in ?? renders fortune symbol (5)
18. Safari ?? conceals master in enigmas (5)

The grid:

[image: The Grid]
Sidenote:

> *Failed in an attempt to achieve symmetry :(*

Comment: Should 14 have 6 letters as in the diagram, or 5 letters as in the clue?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, please see edit, thanks for reminding @El-Guest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1a. Big at first, [Northolt] without direction is flash of lightning (4)
>  B(ig) + (north)OLT = **BOLT**
>
>  3a. Initially courteous, [Harlesden] is king out of lair (7)
>  (C)ourteous + HARLESDEN - DEN (lair) = **CHARLES**
>
>  4a. First half of [Warren (Street)] watched Polish city (6)
>  WAR(ren) + SAW (watched) = **WARSAW**
>
>  5a. First slice of [Aldgate] blended becomes little boy (3)
>  ALD(gate)* = **LAD**
>
>  6a. Beheaded [Becontree] misheard as nation (7)
>  (be)CONTREE homophone = **COUNTRY**
>
>  7a. Head-on horse on [Elm (Park)] with alien makes protective accessory (6)
>  H(orse) + ELM + E.T. = **HELMET**
>
>  9a. A situation around the head of [Stanmore] being Anglican (12)
>  CIRCUM (around) + STAN(more) + CE (Church of England) = **CIRCUMSTANCE**
>
>  10a. Bizarre [Angel], with two more piece of instrument (8)
>  ANGEL* with two more (tripled) = **TRIANGLE** (a musical instrument). Not sure why "piece of", though?
>
>  11a. Talk rudely below the [Temple] (5)
>  (from postmortes in the comments) This is a double definition: **CHEEK** means "to talk rudely" and is also part of the face below the temple.
>
>  1d. Dark part of messy [Wanstead] is unprecedented event (5 4)
>  BLACK (dark) + WANS(tead)* = **BLACK SWAN**
>
>  14d. Poor [Buckhurst] with leg crossed wounds (5)
>  BUCKHURST - BUCK (being poor), with legs (final letters) crossed = **HURTS**
>
>  15d. Extreme [Brixton] in shallow hot open pool is diagonal wanderer
>  B(rixton) I(n) S(hallow) H(ot) O(pen) P(ool) = **BISHOP**
>
>  17d. Counting section in [Seven Sisters] renders fortune symbol (5)
>  The numeral part of Seven Sisters = **SEVEN**
>
>  18d. Safari [Leyton] conceals master in enigmas (5)
>  (safa)RI LEY(ton) = **RILEY**

Finished grid. My own answers are in black, and the ones that were stolen from El-Guest's answer are also in black.

> [image]

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Aaaa I think I've got it! Thanks

Comment: Edited clue for 12D to enhance clarity, pls check :)

Comment: Answer to 11a looks like CHEEK (talk rudely); missing station in the clue *might* be TEMPLE as I can't think of another station that is also part of the face (or maybe lower back :) )

Comment: @postmortes Oh, I see now. Didn't know that was a verb. Thanks!

Comment: all correct, well done! 23k rep now, congrats!

Comment: Fantastic job, @jafe!

Answer (score 4):

Just starting with a couple...

> 2a. Limits of Marble Arch (MAR__CH) show time of year = **MARCH**. 
>  8a. Belsize without misheard alarm (BEL) matters dimensions = **SIZE**. 
>  12d. Nameless Warwick (WARWICK - WAR = WICK) in the past (-ED) = evil = **WICKED**. 
>  13d. Shortened church (CH) ahead of Ickenham without meat (Ickenham - ham = ICKEN) is meat = **CHICKEN**. 
>  16d. Scrambled Arsenal (RAS) following the Honourable (HON) with initialized Delhi University (DU) is American country = **HONDURAS**. 
>  17d. Counting section in Seven Sisters renders fortune symbol = **SEVEN**.

Comment: nice job! all correct so far!